# How to concatenate cells using ARRAYFORMULA across rows and columns?

Tags: formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

I have a document that's a recurring CSV import/export.
I'm trying to concatenate images separated by ", " and using `ARRAYFORMULA` to make it all the way down.

The problem is, I don't know how many images there will be, but I know the maximum is `15`. So if I concatenate, by for instance using `A1+A2...+A15`, I will end up with multiple commas at the end since I don't know how many there is.

I have this so far `=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(", ",FILTER(B3:P3,NOT(B3:P3=""))))` in A2.

Can anyone help with how I can concatenate from `B2:P2` and wrap it in an `ARRAYFORMULA` to go all the way down?

[link to my spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Oiu9LOJpTRaru2a1qw3-lgD1aXfG0MoiRCRa1-46ekY/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 2):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN("♪", 1, 
 QUERY(TRANSPOSE(IF(B2:Z<>"", B2:Z&",", )), 
 "select *", ROWS(B2:B))), "♪", 0)))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In a general sense, the OP seeks to concatenate an array of text with dimensions RxC rowwise, returning an Rx1 array of concatenated text. An earlier answer can be streamlined, using the OP's range of cells.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE( QUERY(TRANSPOSE( IF(B2:P<>"", B2:P&", ", "") ), "select *", COLUMNS(B2:P)) ))
```

The key things to note:

- QUERY(data, query, [headers]) concatenates header text in a columnwise manner, returning a single string per column with header rows' values from the column separated by a space in that single string.
- TRANSPOSE within the QUERY makes rows into columns (CxR).
- "select *" returns all of each column (hence, all of each original row).
- The OP's original rows were COLUMNS(B:P) = C wide.
- Setting the 'headers' argument to COLUMNS(B:P) = C means that each full row in the original range is now in the header section,  where it will be concatenated into a single string with a space separator.
- The final TRANSPOSE returns the 1xR header range to the desired Rx1 result.

Aside from the OP's use case, this approach is useful as an intermediate step in array formulas. For instance, the sequence ROWS( UNIQUE( TRANSPOSE( QUERY( TRANSPOSE( R:C, "select *", COLUMNS(R:C) ))))) would give the count of unique combinations of values across columns by row in the range.